# Editing one item in a list in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a demo [application](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5879/) where I've managed to implement changing all items and sorting all items. Now I would like to update only one item at position [1] in the array of the list so that the list updates. How can I do it?

```
this.changeOne=function(){
this.allItems[1]={name:"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element is `this.allItems()[0]`.

Then, you only need to change the `name` property.

Like this:

```
    this.changeOne=function(){
        this.allItems()[0].name("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
    }
```

In this function you need to check if there is elements (I not checked it!!).

More information at this link [observable arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)